# How to reduce DASK array map blocks execution time?

Tags: arrays, dask, dask-distributed

I wrote my functions using numba njit,then I wrote a total function that uses them in a iteration loop.(for example runs a iteration 5 times)

At last I used dask array.map_blocks to map total funciton across all blocks of a dask array.

But computing(i.e computing result by .compute) is still time consuming.

Is there any way  to decrease it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you read through the documentation on understanding performance: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/understanding-performance.html