How to apply a function to each 2D slice of a 4D Numpy array in parallel with Dask without running out of RAM?
I want to apply a function to each 2D slice of a 4D Numpy array using Dask. The output should be a 2D matrix (the function applied to each 2D slice returns a single value). I would like to do this in parallel. Problem: I'm not sure I understand correctly how Dask implements the parallel calculation. Currently, I am always running out of RAM. My naive understanding is that the entire input array and all currently processed chunks must fit in RAM (+ some extra space for all other applications to work). But it seems that each chunk gets a copy of the input array?
Here's some example code (data will be roughly ~ 20 GiB big). I know there are more efficient ways to compute the sum over the last two dimensions. This is just an example function to illustrate the problem (aka. the question is not about computing the sum over the last two dimensions of a 4D array).
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da

# set seed
np.random.RandomState(42)

# Create example data array
array_shape = (1000,300,50,200)
data = np.random.random(array_shape)  # Create a large 4D NumPy array

# how big is whole array and how big is each chunk?
array_gib = data.nbytes / (1024 ** 3)
chunk_gib = data[0,0,:,:].nbytes / (1024 ** 3)
print(f"Memory occupied by array: {array_gib} GiB, Memory occupied by chunk: {chunk_gib} GiB")

# Define an example function that operates on a 2D slice and returns a single value
def sum_of_2d_slice(chunk):
    return chunk.sum(axis=None)[None,None]

# Define dask array with chunks. We want to iterate over the first two dimensions
# so each chunk is a 2D matrix
data = da.from_array(data, chunks=(1,1,data.shape[2],data.shape[3]))

# Map function to each chunk
result = data.map_blocks(sum_of_2d_slice,drop_axis=[2,3])

# Compute the final result
final_result = result.compute(num_workers=5,processes=True,memory_limit='1GB')

# Print the result
print(final_result)


Do you have to use dask? As is, the dask code is ~3.5x slower than just data.sum(axis=(2, 3)) for me which could easily be sped up with pnumpy or numba

The function above is just an example (didn't want to distract from my main question how RAM is handled with dask). I could of course also use another approach (joblib's Parallel class, etc), but then there's no reason anymore for the question. In theory, dask seems to be a good choice, also in terms of writing less code.

On my machine (Windows + Dask 2022.7.0), in IPython, it does not take significantly more than the 22.3 GiB needed for data. Maybe just 0.1-0.3 GiB but not significantly more than that (hard to be precise since the memory usage fluctuate a bit). The computation is sequential (only 1 core used) and it is very slow by the way (~30 times slower than Numpy)...

Do you know why it is sequential? Because num_workers=5?

Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63140896/how-to-reduce-dask-array-map-blocks-execution-time

data = np.random.random(array_shape): here you create one big numpy array, final_result = result.compute here also, the same size. If you want to avoir loading all that into memory, you need to stream, reading as a dask array, writing to disk in streaming, not computing the whole array.
